# Is there a way to add syntax for a custom datatype in Isabelle?

Tags: functional-programming, isabelle, algebraic-data-types

So I have two custom datatypes:

```
datatype ('a, 't) action = ACTION (name: "'a") (args: "'t list") ("⌈_ _⌋")
```

and

```
datatype ('a, 't) multiaction = MULTIACTION "('a, 't) action multiset" ("⟨(_)⟩")
```

Both of them work with their given notations, however whenever I want to use these data structures in their pretty-printed format, it looks a little redundant. For example:

```
value "⟨{#⌈a b⌋, ⌈c d⌋#}⟩"
```

What I'd like to do is have the above typed without the multiset brackets, so that it looks like this:

```
value "⟨⌈a b⌋, ⌈c d⌋⟩"
```

What I've tried is using syntax:

```
syntax
  "_maction" :: "args ⇒ ('a, 't) multiaction" ("⟨_⟩" [0] 60)
translations
  "⟨x⟩" == "CONST MULTIACTION {#x#}"
```

But when I try it out with some datatypes:

```
value "⟨⌈''x'' [1,2,3::int]⌋⟩"
```

But I get a wellsortedness error, which I have no idea why it occurs. Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is that `pt` type?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the `multiaction` type? You could just introduce that as a type synonym.

Comment: Plus, ‘wellsortedness error’ usually means that something isn't set up correctly for code generation. It should not be related to syntax.

Comment: @ManuelEberl Sorry, that's meant to be a multiaction, not pt. I'll fix that. In the real code, there is more than just the multiaction in that datatype (originally called "pt"), so I don't think I can use a type synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are looking to lift the `multiset` syntax to `multiaction`? In this case, you may also wish to lift the relevant definitions for the `multiset` (as noted in the comments, ideally, you will wish to use the `datatype`/`lift_definition` infrastructure for this):

```
datatype ('a, 't) action = ACTION (name: "'a") (args: "'t list") ("⌈_ _⌋")
datatype ('a, 't) multiaction = MULTIACTION "('a, 't) action multiset"

(*this should not be lifted manually: use the integration of
the datatype and lifting infrastructure*)
fun add_multiaction :: 
  "('a, 'b) action ⇒ ('a, 'b) multiaction ⇒ ('a, 'b) multiaction"
  where "add_multiaction x (MULTIACTION xs) = MULTIACTION (add_mset x xs)"

abbreviation MAempty :: "('a, 't) multiaction" ("⟨#⟩") where
  "MAempty ≡ MULTIACTION {#}"

syntax
  "_multiaction" :: "args ⇒ ('a, 't) multiaction" ("⟨(_)⟩")
translations
  "⟨x, xs⟩" == "CONST add_multiaction x ⟨xs⟩"
  "⟨x⟩" == "CONST add_multiaction x ⟨#⟩"

value "⟨⌈''x'' [1,2,3::int]⌋, ⌈''x'' [1,2,3::int]⌋⟩"
```

---

I have to admit I am not entirely certain if I fully understood what exactly you are trying to achieve: I am providing the first idea that came to my mind based on not-very-thorough understanding of the question.

---

Isabelle version: Isabelle2021-RC6